# Installing Hyper-V, but "We couldn't complete the features" (Undoing changes)

Tags: windows-10, docker, hyper-v

I installed Docker but then realized Hyper-V was not enabled.

It seems I can't enable it.

I tried `DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /All /FeatureName:Microsoft-Hyper-V`,

here is my log `%windir%\Logs\CBS\cbs.log` : [cbs.log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HKmzbl0dDg7mKxYXL58jbIw-kYYt6a_A/view?usp=sharing).

---

I should have all requirements satisfied.

1. I uninstalled VMWare and Docker.
2. I have all the requirements (`systeminfo`):

   - VM Monitor Mode Extensions: Yes
   - Virtualization Enabled In Firmware: Yes
   - Second Level Address Translation: Yes
   - Data Execution Prevention Available: Yes
3. Task Manager > Performance > Virtualization: Enabled.
4. I have the latest Windows 10 updates.
5. I have also checked `sfc /scannow`.

But when I try and restart, I get:

- Getting Windows ready...
- Working on updates...
- Working on features...
- We couldn't complete the features... (Undoing changes)
- We couldn't complete the updates... (Undoing changes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first Error in cbs.log is:

```
2022-08-17 12:29:03, Info                  CSI    00000123 Begin executing advanced installer phase 31 index 0 (sequence 0)
    Old component: [l:0]''
    New component: [l:0]''
    Install mode: delta
    Smart installer: true
    Installer ID: {b1498a21-0405-4959-adaa-7e78686acfbe}
    Installer name: 'Counters Installer'
2022-08-17 12:29:03, Error                 CSI    00000124 (F) PerfCounterInstaller Error: LastCounter and LastHelp are inconsistent (10640,10925).
[gle=0x80004005]
2022-08-17 12:29:03, Error                 CSI    00000125 (F) PerfCounterInstaller Error: Counter database is corrupted, run 'lodctr /R' to fix it.
[gle=0x80004005]
```

Open cmd as administrator and do the following:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>cd..
C:\Windows>cd syswow64
C:\Windows\SysWOW64>lodctr /R
Info: Successfully rebuilt performance counter setting from system backup store
```

Now try `DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /All /FeatureName:Microsoft-Hyper-V` again.